# Kubernetes: Skaffold with Multipass

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold, multipass

I'm developping an application which is splitted in 15 micro services.
I've been using Minikube with skaffold for development.

Now, I want to migrate to multipass nodes.
Is it possible to use skaffold with multipass on Ubuntu 18.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a Kubernetes distribution.  I haven't tested it, but the microk8s documentation describes [installing microk8s on multipass](https://microk8s.io/docs/install-alternatives).

Comment: I've deployed it using k3s, it works fine. Thanks for your answer